# How can I vectorize and speed up this large array calculation?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, vectorization

I'm currently trying to *calculate the sum of all sum of subsquares in a 10.000 x 10.000 array of values*. As an example, if my array was :

```
1 1 1 
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

I want the result to be :

```
1+1+1+2+2+2+3+3+3                        [sum of squares of size 1]
+(1+1+2+2)+(1+1+2+2)+(2+2+3+3)+(2+2+3+3) [sum of squares of size 2]
+(1+1+1+2+2+2+3+3+3)                     [sum of squares of size 3]
________________________________________
68
```

So, as a first try i wrote a very simple python code to do that. As it was in O(k^2.n^2) (n being the size of the big array and k the size of the subsquares we are getting), the processing was awfully long. I wrote another algorithm in O(n^2) to speed it up :

```
def getSum(tab,size):
    n = len(tab)
    tmp = numpy.zeros((n,n))

    for i in xrange(0,n):
        sum = 0
        for j in xrange(0,size):
            sum += tab[j][i]
        tmp[0][i] = sum

        for j in xrange(1,n-size+1):
            sum += (tab[j+size-1][i] - tab[j-1][i])
            tmp[j][i] = sum

    finalsum = 0
    for i in xrange(0,n-size+1):
        sum = 0 
        for j in xrange(0,size):
            sum += tmp[i][j]
        finalsum += sum

        for j in xrange(1,n-size+1):
            finalsum += (tmp[i][j+size-1] - tmp[i][j-1])

return finalsum
```

So this code works fine. Given an array and a size of subsquares, it will return the sum of the values in all this subsquares. I basically iterate over the size of subsquares to get all the possible values.

The problem is this is again waaay to long for big arrays (over 20 days for a 10.000 x 10.000 array). I googled it and learned I could vectorize the iterations over arrays with numpy. However, i couldn't figure out how to make it so in my case...

**If someone can help me to speed my algorithm up, or give me good documentation on the subject, i'll be glad !**

Thank you !

Comment: I think it would get a better approach to calculate the count times of each number in matrix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sliding summations are best suited to be calculated as 2D convolution summations and those could be efficiently calculated with [`scipy's convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html). Thus, for a specific size, you could get the summations, like so -

```
def getSum(tab,size):
    # Define kernel and perform convolution to get such sliding windowed summations
    kernel = np.ones((size,size),dtype=tab.dtype)
    return convolve2d(tab, kernel, mode='valid').sum()
```

To get summations across all sizes, I think the best way both in terms of memory and performance efficiency would be to use a loop to loop over all possible sizes. Thus, to get the final summation, you would have -

```
def getAllSums(tab):
    finalSum = 0
    for i in range(tab.shape[0]):
        finalSum += getSum(tab,i+1)
    return finalSum
```

Sample run -

```
In [51]: tab
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])

In [52]: getSum(tab,1) # sum of squares of size 1
Out[52]: 18

In [53]: getSum(tab,2) # sum of squares of size 2
Out[53]: 32

In [54]: getSum(tab,3) # sum of squares of size 3
Out[54]: 18

In [55]: getAllSums(tab) # sum of squares of all sizes
Out[55]: 68
```

Comment: That's cool. Could you please give the complexity in Big-Oh notation?

Comment: @Sayakiss Well scipy's 2D convolution AFAIK should be implemented in C, so we can say that's vectorized when talking at python-level. So, in terms of O-notation, the entire solution to get the final summation across all sizes should be O(n), where n is the size of `tab`, i.e. number of rows in `tab`.

Comment: Amazing.. Did you mean the complexity of `getSum` is O(n)? But there is n^2 elements in `tab`, just a simple scan of `tab` will cost O(n^2)... I just can't understand the magic behind the `convolve2d`...

Comment: @Sayakiss Think of the scipy's convole2D as doing the same operataions, but in `C`. So, that would be O(n^2) in `C`, which can't exactly be expressed as O notation, but can be thought of as a vectorized operation at python level. But, let's assume that is O(K), so that's getSum. Next up, we have a pure python loop with O(n) complexity at getAllSums. Thus, the total complexity becomes O(K*n), where n is the number of rows in `tab`. Hope that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 6):

Following the excellent idea of @Divakar, I would suggest using [integral images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) to speedup convolutions. If the matrix is very big, you have to convolve it several times (once for each kernel size). Several convolutions (or evaluations of sums inside a square) can be very efficiently computed using integral images (aka summed area tables).

Once an integral image `M` is computed, the sum of all values inside a region `(x0, y0) - (x1, y1)` can be computed with **just** 4 aritmetic computations, **regardless of the size of the window** (picture from wikipedia):

```
M[x1, y1] - M[x1, y0] - M[x0, y1] + M[x0, y0]
```

[image: Link from wikipedia]

This can be very easily vectorized in numpy. An integral images can be calculated with `cumsum`. Following the example:

```
tab = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
M = tab.cumsum(0).cumsum(1) # Create integral images
M = np.pad(M, ((1,0), (1,0)), mode='constant') # pad it with a row and column of zeros
```

`M` is padded with a row and a column of zeros to handle the first row (where `x0 = 0` or `y0 = 0`).

Then, given a window size `W`, the sum of EVERY window of size `W` can be computed efficiently and fully vectorized with numpy as:

```
all_sums = M[W:, W:] - M[:-W, W:] - M[W:, :-W] + M[:-W, :-W]
```

Note that the vectorized operation above, calculates the sum of every window, i.e. every A, B, C, and D of the matrix. The sum of all windows is then calculated as

```
total = all_sums.sum()
```

Note that for `N` different sizes, different to convolutions, the integral image has to be computed only once, thus, the code can be written very efficiently as:

```
def get_all_sums(A):
    M = A.cumsum(0).cumsum(1)
    M = np.pad(M, ((1,0), (1,0)), mode='constant')

    total = 0
    for W in range(1, A.shape[0] + 1):
        tmp = M[W:, W:] + M[:-W, :-W] - M[:-W, W:] - M[W:, :-W]
        total += tmp.sum()

    return total
```

The output for the example:

```
>>> get_all_sums(tab)
68
```

---

Some timings comparing convolutions to integral images with different size matrices. `getAllSums` refeers to Divakar's convolutional method, while `get_all_sums` to the integral images based method described above:

```
>>> R1 = np.random.randn(10, 10)
>>> R2 = np.random.randn(100, 100)
```

1) With `R1` 10x10 matrix:

```
>>> %time getAllSums(R1)
CPU times: user 353 µs, sys: 9 µs, total: 362 µs
Wall time: 335 µs
2393.5912717342017

>>> %time get_all_sums(R1)
CPU times: user 243 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 243 µs
Wall time: 248 µs
2393.5912717342012
```

2) With `R2` 100x100 matrix:

```
>>> %time getAllSums(R2)
CPU times: user 698 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 698 ms
Wall time: 701 ms
176299803.29826894

>>> %time get_all_sums(R2)
CPU times: user 2.51 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.51 ms
Wall time: 2.47 ms
176299803.29826882
```

Note that using integral images is 300 times faster than convolutions for large enough matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Based the idea to calculate how many times each number counted, I came to this simple code:

```
def get_sum(matrix, n):
    ret = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(1, n + 1):
                # k is the square size. count is times of the number counted.
                count = min(k, n - k + 1, i + 1, n - i) * min(k, n - k + 1, j + 1, n - j)
                ret += count * matrix[i][j]
    return ret

a = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

print get_sum(a, 3) # 68
```

---

Divakar's solution is fantastic, however, I think mine could be more efficient, at least in asymptotical time complexity (O(n^3) compared with Divakar's O(n^3logn)).

---

I get a O(n^2) solution now...

Basically, we can get that:

```
def get_sum2(matrix, n):
    ret = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            x = min(i + 1, n - i)
            y = min(j + 1, n - j)
            # k < half
            half = (n + 1) / 2
            for k in range(1, half + 1):
                count = min(k, x) * min(k, y)
                ret += count * matrix[i][j]
            # k >= half
            for k in range(half + 1, n + 1):
                count = min(n + 1 - k, x) * min(n + 1 - k, y)
                ret += count * matrix[i][j]
    return ret
```

You can see `sum(min(k, x) * min(k, y))` can be calculated in O(1) when 1 <= k <= n/2

So we came to that O(n^2) code:

```
def get_square_sum(n):
    return n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6


def get_linear_sum(a, b):
    return (b - a + 1) * (a + b) / 2


def get_count(x, y, k_end):
    # k <= min(x, y), count is k*k
    sum1 = get_square_sum(min(x, y))

    # k > min(x, y) and k <= max(x, y), count is k * min(x, y)
    sum2 = get_linear_sum(min(x, y) + 1, max(x, y)) * min(x, y)

    # k > max(x, y), count is x * y
    sum3 = x * y * (k_end - max(x, y))

    return sum1 + sum2 + sum3


def get_sum3(matrix, n):
    ret = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            x = min(i + 1, n - i)
            y = min(j + 1, n - j)
            half = n / 2

            # k < half
            ret += get_count(x, y, half) * matrix[i][j]
            # k >= half
            ret += get_count(x, y, half + half % 2) * matrix[i][j]

    return ret
```

Test:

```
a = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
n = 1000
b = [[1] * n] * n
print get_sum3(a, 3) # 68
print get_sum3(b, n) # 33500333666800
```

You can rewrite my O(n^2) Python code to C and I believe it will result a very efficient solution...

Comment: Quite smart idd! To make it even better you could move `half` and `half + half % 2` as constants outside of the loop!